# Missing entries in "most viewed" in 10k tools?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools, views

Super User does not have the huge traffic Stack Overflow has, but this week a question got [243k views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74854/over-243-000-views-in-3-days) in just 3 days. However: even though this question right now still gets 500 views per hour, the "Most viewed" list in the 10k tools does not show that in [the stats for today](https://superuser.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today), and nor did it yesterday when still at 2,000 views per hour:

[image: Statistics for most viewed today]

Likewise: not for [the last 2 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oLcq.png). Only when looking at 7 days or more, one gets to see it:

[image: Statistics for most viewed last 7 days]

This makes me wonder about the other entries in the list. (And how we could validate that. The question was originally migrated from Stack Overflow, but I doubt that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm going to add some subtitles to that screen; but to explain: the key here is that the date-filter is on the *creation* date - so the "today" view there is "posts created today, by highest view-count". That post was created on the 10th.

Comment: Amai, somehow I feel stupid for not even *thinking* about that! :-) (But the new subtitles are nice, thanks.)

Comment: Ugh. Could you please move these descriptions to a tooltip or something? After the major changes on that page, it's *even more* cluttered now. :(